# How to create Date placeholder in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, placeholder

In the following code:

```
SELECT
"date placeholder"
FROM table_name
```

what should be written instead of "date placeholder" in order to have a date placeholder which does not have a hard-coded assigned value?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cast (null as date) as mydateplaceholder
```